# TypeScript separate declaration and class implemention like C++ headers using `.d.ts`

Tags: typescript, oop, namespaces, declaration, implementation

Is it possible to separate declaration and implementation of TypeScript classes within a namespace in a similar style to how C++? I want my TypeScript objects to be separated in a similar style to how C++ headers files are using only for declaration and the logic is implemented in a separate file. My goal in doing this is to obfuscate my module logic and only have the declaration exposed when others download my module.

To run my sample I do the following using the code from my test file directly below.

```
tsc
tsc Member.test.ts && node Member.test.js
```

Member.test.ts

```
import { MyNamspace} from "../dist/Member";

var member = new Made.Member();
member.say("Bam");
```

In `Member.d.ts` I want to declare the methods and properties of my class.

```
export declare namespace MyNamspace { 
    export class Member {
      firstName: string;

      constructor(firstName:string);

      getFirstName(): string;
      say(s: string): string;
  }  
}
```

Then in `Member.ts` I want to implement those methods. An initial problem I'm facing is this file is not aware of the `firstName` property from the class I declared in `Member.d.ts`

```
namespace MyNamspace { 
  class Member {     
    constructor(firstName:string) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public getFirstName(): string {
      return this.firstName;
    }
    public say(s: string): void {
      console.log(s + '\n');
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: You are going about it the wrong way. Typescript supports generating definition files from ts source code. You can then expose just the definition, and do as you will with the resulting JS. Ts does not support `d.ts` and `.ts` for the same piece of code

Comment: Look for `--declaration` here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html